# HTML Radiobutton validation in Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <input id="tid" type="radio" name="t" value="">
    <label for="tid">
        Technology</label>

    <input id="sid" type="radio" name="t" value="">
    <label for="sid">
        Science</label>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return xyz()" />


 <script>
        function xyz() {

            var x = document.getElementsByName("t");
            var isChecked = false;
            var message = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

                if (x[i].checked) {

                    isChecked = true;
                    message = x[i].nextSibling().innerHTML;
                    alert(message);
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (isChecked == false) {
                alert("Select");

            }

            return false;



        }
```

I'm unable to get the text alertbox; Why is the NextSibling Method not working here? is getelementbyname also gets the Label associated with the radiobutton? or will it gets the array of only radiobuttons?I don't want to use Value field..thks...

Comment: Its a property not a function. Use `message = x[i].nextSibling.innerHTML;`

Comment: sorry, I'm getting undefined message..any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Pv6EJ/

`nextSibling()` is wrong

use

```
message = x[i].nextSibling.innerHTML;
```

call you javascript function  like this

```
onclick="xyz()";
```

not

```
OnClick="return xyz()"
```

Answer (score 0):

`nextSibling` is a property not a function. Use is like this:

`message = x[i].nextSibling.innerHTML;`

The reason you are getting undefined is because there is no `innerHTML` persent in the radio buttons. If you want to retrieve the value stored in the `<label>` tag, you need to set the value of the radio button as the label text and then use the value property:
HTML:

```
<input id="tid" type="radio" name="t" value="tech">
    <label for="tid">
        Technology</label>
<input id="sid" type="radio" name="t" value="science">
<label for="sid">
    Science</label>
```

Javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i].checked) {
                isChecked = true;
                message = x[i].value;
                alert(message);
                break;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

nextSibling is a property not a function and instead of nextSibling use nextElementSibling  since nextSibling will return the text node

```
message = x[i].nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle [test link with your example](http://jsfiddle.net/uTrwN/)

Change this

```
 message = x[i].nextSibling().innerHTML;
```

to

```
 message = x[i].nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML;
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers